# Convert name-value pair to function argument in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm writing an R function, say foo().  I want to be able to pass in the name and value of parameters to evaluate within a function inside foo().  For example:

```
foo = function(inputArg, inputVal){
  return( rnorm(100, inputArg=inputVal) )
}
```

Then, I could evaluate

```
foo("sd", 2)
```

and get a vector of 100 random normal values with standard deviation equal to 2.  How can I do this?

Comment: Very minor point: it might help if you used something other than `outer`, like `foo`, to make it clear that you're not referring to the _actual_ function by that name.

Comment: @joran: Good point, I've updated the post.

Comment: If you don't _need_ to have a two-arguments function, you could `foo = function(...) rnorm(100, ...)`; `foo(mean = 10)` ; `foo(sd = 10)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this situation, it's best to use the `do.call` syntax which allows you to pass all the parameters as a list. For example

```
foo = function(inputArg, inputVal){
  args <- list(100, inputVal)
  names(args) <- c("", inputArg)
  do.call(rnorm, args)
}
```

and we can call that just as you expect.

```
foo("sd", 2)
```

Here `args` is just a regular list where each element corresponds to a value you would pass as a parameter. You set the names of the list if you want to have named parameters. If you want to leave a parameter as positional (unnamed), set it's name to `""`.